# How come fetch only works here when I add an alert to the end of the line? Express + NodeJS + Fetch. What's a good fix here

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I'm using NodeJS w/ Express to create a web app that records your audio using the VMSG library and posts the BLOB audio to my file system using HTTP Requests and multer. It also adds that instance of a recording into a MongoDB database.

I'm having an issue with the fetch command. It's not working unless I put an alert right after the fetch. The way I have it set up is that I have my main express app (index.js), and a router to the /recordingsDirectory (recordings.js) which is the endpoint for processing the posts. My main index HTML page uses Handlebars and uses a separate JS script (recorder.js) to 1) use the VMSG library and 2) fetch a POST to the /recordingsDirectory once someone submits the audio file w/ the name and the AudioBlob present. This is where I'm stuck. I can fetch in recorder.js with an alert line after the fetch, but I can't have the fetch on the end of the else if block by itself. I'd like to do it without this since the alert is ugly. A solution I've tried is that I tried to make the onsubmit function async and await fetch since I thought maybe it's waiting for a promise but that didn't work.

Here are the files. I commented CRITICAL and SUPER CRITICAL to the lines of code that you should check out and I think where the issues lie:

**index.js**

```js
 const express = require('express')
    const handlebars = require('express-handlebars')
    const path = require('path')
    const XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    const db = require('./db')

const app = express()

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000

app.set('view engine', 'hbs')

app.engine('hbs', handlebars({
    layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'layouts'),
    extname: 'hbs',
    defaultLayout: 'index',
    partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'partials'),
}))

app.use(express.json())

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err instanceof SyntaxError && err.status === 400 && 'body' in err) {
      return res.status(400).send({ status: 404, message: err.message })
  }
  next()
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('main', {
      title: 'Main Page'
  })
})

app.get('/recordings', (req, res) => {
  var database = db.get().db('AudioJungle')
  database.collection('recordings').find().sort({ "date": -1 }).toArray(function(err,       docs) {
    res.render('recordings', {
      title: 'Recordings',
      recordings: docs
    })
  })
})

// CRITICAL
app.use('/recordingsDirectory', require('./recordings/recordings'))

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.use('/scripts', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'vmsg')))

db.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Unable to connect to Mongo.')
    process.exit(1)
  } else {
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on Port: ${PORT}`))
  }
})

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  db.close(function () {
    console.log('Disconnected on app termination');
    process.exit(0);
  });
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).send({
      status: 404,
      error: 'Not found'
    })
})
```

**recordings.js (Aka the /recordingsDirectory endpoint for a fetch POST)**

```js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const multer = require('multer')
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const db = require('../db')
const { ObjectId } = require('bson')
const moment = require('moment')

const upload = multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, callback) => {
            let path = './public/uploads'
            fs.mkdirsSync(path)
            callback(null, path)
        },
        filename: (req, file, callback) => {
            createRecording(req).then((id) => {
                var file_name = id + '.mp3'
                callback(null, file_name)
            })
        }
    })
})

var type = upload.single('audio-file')

// CRITICAL
router.post('/', type, (req, res) => {
    console.log('made it')
    res.status(200)
    res.send('OK')
})

router.delete('/delete', (req, res) => {
    deleteRecording(req.body._id).then((dbResponse) => {
        if (dbResponse == null || dbResponse == undefined) {
            res.status(400).json({ msg: 'ID already deleted' })
        } else {
            res.status(200)
        }
    })
})

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var database = db.get().db('AudioJungle')
    var recordings = database.collection('recordings')
    recordings.findOne({"_id": ObjectId(req.query.id)}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err

        if (result == null || result == undefined) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                status: 404,
                error: 'Recording no longer in the database'
            })
        }
        res.status(200)
        res.json({
            name: result.name,
            date: result.date
        })
    })
})

async function createRecording(req) {
    var database = db.get().db('AudioJungle')
    var recordings = database.collection('recordings')
    var audioObject = {
        name: req.body.name,
        date: moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
    }

    var dbResponse = await recordings.insertOne(audioObject)
    return dbResponse.insertedId
}

async function deleteRecording(id) {
    var database = db.get().db('AudioJungle')
    var recordings = database.collection('recordings')
    var audioToDelete = {
        _id: ObjectId(id)
    }

    var deleteResult = await recordings.deleteOne(audioToDelete)
    return deleteResult
}

module.exports = router
```

And below is the Script the audio and name and tries to Fetch (where I need the alert for it to actually process into the /recordingsdirectory)

**recorder.js**

```js
import { record } from "/scripts/vmsg.js";

let recordButton = document.getElementById("record");

var blobObj = null

recordButton.onclick = function() {
  record({wasmURL: "/scripts/vmsg.wasm"}).then(blob => {
    blobObj = blob
    
    var tag = document.createElement("p")
    tag.id="finishedRecording"
    var text = document.createTextNode("Audio File Recorded")
    tag.appendChild(text)
    var element = document.getElementById("box")
    element.appendChild(tag)
    document.getElementById('box').appendChild(a)
  })
}

let form = document.getElementById('mp3Form');

form.addEventListener("submit", submitAudio) 

function submitAudio() {
  var fileName = form.elements[0].value

  if (fileName == "") {
    alert('Please enter a name for your file')
  } else if (blobObj != null) {
  // CRITICAL
  // SUPER CRITICAL WHERE FETCH DOESN'T WORK UNLESS I PUT AN ALERT AT THE END
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('name', fileName) 
    formData.append('audio-file', blobObj)
    
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    }

    fetch('/recordingsDirectory', options);
    // If I comment an alert here, /recordingsDirectory will process the post since it console.logs 'made it'
  } else {
    alert('Record some Audio to upload')
  }
}
```

Here's my file system.

[image]

Also, I'd like to mention that the fetch works properly on my Windows PC without having to add the alert, but it doesn't work without the alert on my macbook. If any one figures out a fix or an error in how I'm doing things to allow this please let me know. I've been stuck on this problem for a day now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You need to prevent the default form submit process. The alert is simply blocking it

Comment: @charlietfl Sweet! This solved the problem, but can I ask what exactly does preventDefault do to solve this problem? I'm quite confused on how this fixes it.

Comment: When you add a submit event listener it runs before the final submit occurs unless you prevent the default. Browser will send the form internally to the `action` url of form or current url if no action exists. Prevent default stops that